# Why a Google App Engine app is one-to-one with GCP project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

What is the reason why in Google Cloud a project can only host 1 App Engine application? More projects are required to host more GAE applications... Why is that?

Comment: This is a design decision Google made years ago. Stackoverflow can help you with programming questions, not the decision path that vendors chose for what features to offer and in what format. Google Cloud was very different in 2008 when App Engine was released compared to the very large feature set today.

Comment: Sure however someone can still help me to understand the reason as somehow you did.

Answer (score 1):

There must be an architectural reason behind the scenes for that, however, you will not be able to find it in any document from GCP. One of the reasons may be the fact that App Engine deploys the default service on a domain based on your project's ID such as "https://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com", and providing multiple apps inside the same project would be hard for Google to manage when you can also have services for each application.

In the end, the real reason for this is most likely confidential and you would not be able to find much in their public documentations aside from some bits that are written in docs such as [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/console/) or [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/an-overview-of-app-engine) that do not really provide much insight in the 
 behind the scenes architecture.

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to host multiple apps on **Google App Engine** by identifying them as separate services.

In order to achieve that you'll need to add the following line to your **app.yaml** file:

```
service: servicename
```

Keep in mind that if you are deploying an app to the GAE in your project for the first time, you shouldn't specify the service as the first one has to be **default**.

Comment: yes, that is the microservice approach. But my point was more to understand why Google has by design used such "limitation".